# How to pass terraform locals variables into AWS resource template body

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to apply aws conformance pack to my aws account using terraform. I am using the sample aws config rules in cloudformation syntax provided in the awslabs repository.

Now from an example conformance pack provided on AWS documentation we have this:

```
resource "aws_config_conformance_pack" "s3conformancepack" {
  name = "s3conformancepack"

  template_body = <<EOT

Resources:
  S3BucketPublicReadProhibited:
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
    Properties:
      ConfigRuleName: S3BucketPublicReadProhibited
      Description: >- 
        Checks that your Amazon S3 buckets do not allow public read access.
        The rule checks the Block Public Access settings, the bucket policy, and the
        bucket access control list (ACL).
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_PUBLIC_READ_PROHIBITED
      MaximumExecutionFrequency: Six_Hours
  S3BucketPublicWriteProhibited: 
    Type: "AWS::Config::ConfigRule"
    Properties: 
      ConfigRuleName: S3BucketPublicWriteProhibited
      Description: "Checks that your Amazon S3 buckets do not allow public write access. The rule checks the Block Public Access settings, the bucket policy, and the bucket access control list (ACL)."
      Scope: 
        ComplianceResourceTypes: 
        - "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      Source: 
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_PUBLIC_WRITE_PROHIBITED
      MaximumExecutionFrequency: Six_Hours
  S3BucketReplicationEnabled: 
    Type: "AWS::Config::ConfigRule"
    Properties: 
      ConfigRuleName: S3BucketReplicationEnabled
      Description: "Checks whether the Amazon S3 buckets have cross-region replication enabled."
      Scope: 
        ComplianceResourceTypes: 
        - "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      Source: 
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_REPLICATION_ENABLED
  S3BucketSSLRequestsOnly: 
    Type: "AWS::Config::ConfigRule"
    Properties: 
      ConfigRuleName: S3BucketSSLRequestsOnly
      Description: "Checks whether S3 buckets have policies that require requests to use Secure Socket Layer (SSL)."
      Scope: 
        ComplianceResourceTypes: 
        - "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      Source: 
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_SSL_REQUESTS_ONLY
  ServerSideEncryptionEnabled: 
    Type: "AWS::Config::ConfigRule"
    Properties: 
      ConfigRuleName: ServerSideEncryptionEnabled
      Description: "Checks that your Amazon S3 bucket either has S3 default encryption enabled or that the S3 bucket policy explicitly denies put-object requests without server side encryption."
      Scope: 
        ComplianceResourceTypes: 
        - "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      Source: 
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED
  S3BucketLoggingEnabled: 
    Type: "AWS::Config::ConfigRule"
    Properties: 
      ConfigRuleName: S3BucketLoggingEnabled
      Description: "Checks whether logging is enabled for your S3 buckets."
      Scope: 
        ComplianceResourceTypes: 
        - "AWS::S3::Bucket"
      Source: 
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: S3_BUCKET_LOGGING_ENABLED
EOT
}
```

Now in my terraform code I will pick one of the config rules in the example provided in the awslabs repo, which is this

```
AcmCertificateExpirationCheck:
    Properties:
      ConfigRuleName: acm-certificate-expiration-check
      InputParameters:
        daysToExpiration:
          Fn::If:
          - acmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AWS::NoValue
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - AWS::ACM::Certificate
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: ACM_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRATION_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
```

Now I have a section in the above snippet where we have an **if statement** that checks for the **variable acmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration**, then is passed the value **Ref: AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration** that references a **parameter**:

```
AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration:
    Default: '90'
    Type: String
```

Now in my terraform code this **parameter** would be set like this:

```
locals {
 AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration = var.acm_certificate_expiration_check_param_days_to_expiration != ""

}

variable acm_certificate_expiration_check_param_days_to_expiration {
  type = string
  default = "90"
}
```

Now I want to use this in the **conformance pack** resource in terraform. So how do I use the if section in a **terraform** way:

```
resource "aws_config_conformance_pack" "s3conformancepack" {
  name = "s3conformancepack"

  template_body = <<EOT

Resources:
  AcmCertificateExpirationCheck:
    Properties:
      ConfigRuleName: acm-certificate-expiration-check
      InputParameters:
        daysToExpiration:
          Fn::If:
          - acmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration  <======[ How to pass the locals variable into this as done on cloudformation or is this ${local.AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration} sufficient ]
          - Ref: AWS::NoValue
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - AWS::ACM::Certificate
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: ACM_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRATION_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
```

Answer (score 0):

In my question I have this code snipet:

```
AcmCertificateExpirationCheck:
    Properties:
      ConfigRuleName: acm-certificate-expiration-check
      InputParameters:
        daysToExpiration:
          Fn::If:
          - acmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AWS::NoValue
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
        - AWS::ACM::Certificate
      Source:
        Owner: AWS
        SourceIdentifier: ACM_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRATION_CHECK
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
```

This section:

```
InputParameters:
        daysToExpiration:
          Fn::If:
          - acmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration
          - Ref: AWS::NoValue
```

can be written as:

```
InputParameters:
        daysToExpiration: ${local.AcmCertificateExpirationCheckParamDaysToExpiration ? var.acm_certificate_expiration_check_param_days_to_expiration : null}
```

I tested this on AWS and it deployed successfully